# Execution of a SQL query in Java?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a bit of a problem while the answer might be pretty clear.
I'm trying to execute a parser program which converts data to a SQL Database but I can't execute a statement, which is pretty logical.
Is there a way that this issue can be fixed?
Thanks for the help =)

**Maybe this makes it more clear:**

```
public int parser(String a, float b2, float c2) {
    int updated = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try{

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    // get a statement
        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO testparser(garagenaam, xpos, ypos) VALUES(" + a + "," + b2 + "," + c2 +")";
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

        stmt.setString(1, a);
        stmt.setFloat(2, b2);
        stmt.setFloat(3, c2);

        updated = stmt.executeUpdate();

        System.out.println("Inserted data into the database...");


        } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
        }
        try {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Thank you for your service.");
    this.conn = conn;
    return updated;

}
```

Comment: 1. What's the error you're getting?
2. Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: So firstly, the field `this.conn` is not the same as the local variable `conn`. We don't know how/if you set the field, but we see that the local variable it shadows is only ever assigned `null`. If you're getting NPEs, that's why. Otherwise, please update your question to describe what specifically "I can't" means. What errors are you seeing?

Comment: `stmt.executeUpdate` method takes a `String` as argument, not a `ResultSet`. Does this code even compile?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question with the rest of the code. It compiles the first line of data, afterwards it wants to send it to the database but gets stuck there.

Comment: Your SQL update statements are wrong and it's not Java's fault. Your Java code is also wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for updating the question. If you want to add a single row with three values, you don't do that by executing three statements -- you execute one statement, whose `values(...)` tuple specifies all three values for that row. There are examples at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html (search for the header titled "Examples").

Comment: I had it in one statement at first, and it did compile all the lines but wasn't able to be sent to the database. So I did some googling and researching and found out about this way but besides reverting it back to 1 execution statement, I think I would hit my head against the same problem which is that I can't properly execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the weirdness with the conn variable the others have mentioned -- You can do the insert for all column in one update statement.  And you should use a PreparedStatement for this to avoid SQL problems or Injection.

```
public int parser(String a, float b2, float c2) {
         // because I don't know where the conn is coming from
         conn = getConnection(); 

         // get a statement 
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO testparser(garagename, xpos, ypos) VALUES(?,?,?)";
         PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);

          stmt.setString(1, a);
          stmt.setFloat(2, b2);
          stmt.setFloat(3, c2);

          int updated = stmt.executeUpdate();

          System.out.println("Inserted data into the database...");
```

... imagine try/catch/finally with closing of stuff as appropriate  :)

```
          return updated;
      }
```

Comment: caveat... didn't test this, just hand-jammed... but should be pretty close.  :)   and you will want all the closing and such too...

Comment: I'll try it, one second, thanks in advance for the effort though ^^

Comment: Okay, I updated my coding with your advice and the only problem I seem to be running into is that whenever I do it that way and define conn, which stands in this code for connection with:
''conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);''
, I seem to be getting the problem that I get an error with:
''if (stmt != null)''
as it is cannot resolve the ''stmt'' so I do that by putting a
"Statement stmt = null;"
before the try { but that isn't allowed as PreparedStatement already takes stmt (I wrote this with spacing to make it clearer, didn't go through..)

Comment: I put in a 3rd addition to the question to maybe clarify some things haha